# What models are used by Google Cloud Natural Language?

Tags: google

To restate the question posed in the title, what models are used by Google Cloud Natural Language? I know that it says "AutoML," but is there any indication of what kinds of models are used behind the scenes. Any insights  would be greatly helpful.